# Use configuration properties in Spring expression language

Tags: spring, configurationproperties, spring-expression-language

I have a class with configuration properties:

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("message-starter")
public class JobProperties {

    public Duration kafkaSendingPeriod;
    public Duration rabbitSendingPeriod;
}
```

And class that aggregates this properties and uses them in @Scheduled annotation using Spring expression language:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JobProperties.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Job {

    public final JobProperties jobProperties;

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString="#{@jobProperties.getKafkaSendingPeriod()}")
    public void fun(){
        System.out.println("Time: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

But when I run it I get the following exception:

```
Description:

A component required a bean named 'jobProperties' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'jobProperties' in your configuration.
```

Please tell me how to fix this exception so that I can get the value of the fields of the JobProperties class?

Comment: is `JobProperties` defined as bean or as `@EnableConfigurationProperties(JobProperties.class)`?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov your ask helped me, it need add `@Component` annotation over `JobProperties`, thank you!